# clustering in Item-based collaborative filtering

Tags: machine-learning, recommender-system

I read about  item-based collaborative filtering in the paper from Sawar et al. I want to apply clustering on items to find the most similar items and then apply the prediction. Is this a good approach?  Are there any references which use this type of item-clustering approach.  thanks

**References**

Badrul Sarwar, George Karypis, Joseph Konstan, and John Riedl. 2001. Item-based collaborative filtering recommendation algorithms. In Proceedings of the 10th international conference on World Wide Web (WWW '01). ACM, New York, NY, USA, 285-295. Retrieved from http://files.grouplens.org/papers/www10_sarwar.pdf